# Read cookies with JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, cookies

I know how to write/create cookies in JavaScript.........................................................

```
//Create the cookies
document.cookie = "Name=" + Name + ";expires=Friday, 31-Dec-2011 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
document.cookie = "Surname=" + Surname + ";expires=Friday, 31-Dec-2011 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
document.cookie = "Number=" + Number + ";expires=Friday, 31-Dec-2011 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
document.cookie = "Email=" + Email + ";expires=Friday, 31-Dec-2011 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
document.cookie = "Country=" + Country + ";expires=Friday, 31-Dec-2011 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
document.cookie = "Company=" + Company + ";expires=Friday, 31-Dec-2011 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
document.cookie = "Title=" + Job + ";expires=Friday, 31-Dec-2011 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
```

But how can I read each one of them in JavaScript because I want to populate the text boxes next time the user come to the form?

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
var cookieName = ReadCookie("Name");
document.getElementById('txtName').value = cookieName;
```

**Edit with Answer:**

I used this code....................................

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getCookie(c_name)
{
  if (document.cookie.length>0)
  {
      c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
      if (c_start!=-1)
        {
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
        if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
     }
     return "";
 }

function checkCookie()
{
    Name = getCookie('Name');
    Surname = getCookie('Surname');
    Email = getCookie('Email');
    Company = getCookie('Company');
    Title = getCookie('Title');

    if (Email!=null && Email!="")
      {
      //Populate the text boxes..................................
      document.FormName.txtName.value = Name;
      document.FormName.txtSurname.value = Surname;
      document.FormName.txtEmail.value = Email;
      document.FormName.txtCompany.value = Company;
      document.FormName.txtjob.value = Title;
      }
   }

</script>
```

And called the checkCookie() function like so from the window.onload

```
<SCRIPT TYPE='text/javascript' LANGUAGE='JavaScript'><!--    //

window.onload = initPage;

function initPage() 
{
    checkCookie();

}
```

//-->

Enjoy!!

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: @Kon - that is a much better reference than the w3schools.

Comment: Eh, quirksmode is okay... but a bit verbose with all the substring'ing -- try http://leaverou.me/2009/12/reading-cookies-the-regular-expression-way/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

set cookie

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
}
```

get cookie

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
if (document.cookie.length>0)
  {
  c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  if (c_start!=-1)
    {
    c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;
    c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
    if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
  }
return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are *much* *much* better references than w3schools (the most awful web reference ever made):

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Examples derived from these references:

```
// sets the cookie cookie1
document.cookie =
 'cookie1=test; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'

// sets the cookie cookie2 (cookie1 is *not* overwritten)
document.cookie =
 'cookie2=test; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'

// remove cookie2
document.cookie = 'cookie2=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'
```

The mozilla reference even has a nice cookie library you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to `document.cookie` gets you the whole string of cookies.  They're separated by semicolons.

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';'); // "cookies" will be an array
```

You could then make that an object with name->value mapping:

```
var cookieMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
  cookies[i].replace(/^\s*([^=]+)=(.*)$/, function(_, name, val) {
    cookieMap[name] = unescape(val);
  });
}
```

Now you can look at a cookie "mycookie" like this:

```
var mycookieVal = cookieMap.mycookie;
```

**note** this is been edited since its initial broken version - still the same idea but not it should actually work. The idea is that the loop takes each of the parts of `document.cookie` that were separated by semicolons, and then further splits each of those into a name part (stuff before the "=", except leading spaces) and a "value" part (stuff after the "=" to the end of the cookie part).  The value is then stored in the "cookieMap" under the given name.

Comment: Cool, but how do I get an individual one?

Comment: I just extended my answer - there are other suggestions in other answers too, like functions to return specific cookies without having to build a map.

Comment: var mycookieVal = cookieMap.Name; Correct?

Comment: Yes but in my example the name of the cookie is "mycookie".  Sorry about all the errors in my original; it should be all fixed now.  I'm not sure whether you need the "unescape" that's in another one of the answers.

Comment: I'll do some more work on my answer; this is a simple problem but I've made a mess for myself (and for you!).

Comment: MMMM, the value "name" in your code is my cookie name correct that I am looking for? This does not work for me still.........