# How to get cookies using js?

Tags: javascript, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “best” way to get and set a single cookie value using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260749/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-and-set-a-single-cookie-value-using-javascript)
>   [Read cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905142/read-cookies-with-javascript)

When I `print_r( $_COOKIE );` in php,  I am getting following result.

```
Array ( [filters] => Array ( [cat] => 1 ) )
```

Now I want to get value of `cat` from cookies using JavaScript.

### I have tried this:

```
 function getCookies() {

      var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
      var cookies = {};
      for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
        var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
        cookies[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
      }
      return cookies;
}
```

When I alert returned result from above function then I am getting an `[object Object]`. But I don't know how to get value of **cat** from that object.

How to know value of `cat` from that returned object ?

Thanks

Comment: @Widor: I have read but I want to go deep in cookies array. I have tried it but getting `undefined`.

Comment: @Student that is an entirely different question. If you're trying to figure out why your code doesn't work, don't ask "how do I do `X`?" Ask a question **about your code.**

Comment: Don't be so quick to close a question without pointing out errors in my question and without giving me time to explain my question using **Edit** option..

Answer (score 3):

[`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie). You might also like to read [Quirksmode – Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

---

***Edit** re OP edit:*

> When I alert returned result from above function then I am getting an [object Object]. But I don't know how to get value of cat from that object.
>
> How to know value of cat from that returned object ?

The problem is that **`alert()` sucks for debugging.** Anything you pass to `alert` is converted to a string, but objects don't have a terribly useful `toString()` method. Use a real debugger (and `console.log()` instead of `alert()`) instead.

See [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-do-you-debug-your-javascript-code)

Answer (score 1):

I believe a Google search would serve you better than a SO post. With that being said, the code below is one of dozens of examples that appears when I [Googled "javascript get cookie"](http://www.google.com/?q=javascript+get+cookie).

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var begin = dc.indexOf(name);
    var end = (dc.indexOf(";", begin) == -1) ? dc.length : dc.indexOf(";", begin);

    return unescape(dc.substring((begin + (name.length + 1)), end));
}
```

Comment: I have tried these but getting `undefined` for this specific Cookie array as defined in my question ?

Comment: How will I call above function to get value of `cat` in cookie array ?