# How to store and read cookies with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I don't know if this type of question would have been asked before but i don't care because some of their answers haven't been clear enough in my opinion. I have created a sample page which will take in a random input and store it as a cookie, which works fine. But what i want to achieve is that par example if the page was reloaded or you closed and re-opened the browser and you clicked on the textbox, the input you entered before will be available to you to use again.

Here is my Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cookie_Saver()
        {
            var cookieV = document.forms["sampleform"]["samplebox"].value;
            var theDate = new Date(2014, 07, 09);
            theDate = theDate.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = "text="+cookieV+";expires="+theDate;
            alert("Done");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="sampleform">
        Enter Cookie Text<input type="text" name="samplebox" id="samplecookiebox">
        <button type="button" onclick="cookie_Saver()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

I want to be able to do this with **html and javascript only** your input would be really appreciated

Comment: Using cookies for this is *soooo* last millennium. Try `localStorage` instead ;)

Comment: Banana, as i said, i already checked other questions, and they were not clear enough, thats why i asked this question already

Comment: You could at least say *what* wasn't clear if you insist on having a new question. Something like: "*I'm trying to do X, I found Q1 & Q2 that were similar, but point Y wasn't clear. What does Y mean?*"...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the getCookie function from [Read cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905142/read-cookies-with-javascript)

```
    function cookie_loader()
    {
        document.forms["sampleform"]["samplebox"].value = getCookie("text");

    }
```

Put this call this function onLoad.