# How to access cookies in handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, hbs

I want to check in home page that user is logged in or not. I have stored jwt token in cookies. For authentication I want to use cookies in handlebars.

Comment: It does not matter what framework you are using you can read them using the cookies API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905142/read-cookies-with-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

Controller

```
const express = require('express');
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser())

app.engine('handlebars', engine());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const isLogin = checkLogin(req.cookies.jwt); // Check login here
  res.render('home', { isLogin });
});
```

View

```
<h1>{{ isLogin }}</h1>
```

Comment: Where is the `checkLogin` defined?

Comment: That's a placeholder. You have to write your own `checkLogin` function